# Reverse Rolling mean for DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan, shift, rolling-computation

I am trying to create a fixture difficulty grid using a DataFrame. I want the mean for the next 5 fixtures for each team.

I’m currently using df.rolling(5, min_periods=1).mean().shift(-4). This is working for the start but is pulling NANs at the end. I understand why NANs are returned – there is no DF to shift up. Ideally I’d like the NANs to become mean across the remaining values, value against 38 just being its current value?

Fixture difficulties

```
ARS AVL BHA BOU                  
3   4   3   2    
2   2   2   2    
5   2   2   4
4   2   5   3
3   2   2   2
```

Mean of next 5 fixtures

```
ARS AVL BHA BOU        
3.4 2.4 2.8 2.6    
3.2 2.4 2.8 2.6    
3.6 2.4 3.2 2.6    
3   2.4 3.6 2.6    
2.6 2.4 3   2.4
```

NAN on last records as nothing to shift up.

```
3.2 3.6 2.8 3.6    
nan nan nan nan    
nan nan nan nan    
nan nan nan nan    
nan nan nan nan
```

Can I adapt this approach or need a different one altogether to populate the NANs?

Comment: So you want `fillna`, not *reverse rolling mean* as in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need inverse values by indexing, use rolling and inverse back:

```
df1 = df.iloc[::-1].rolling(5, min_periods=1).mean().iloc[::-1]
print (df1)
   ARS  AVL   BHA   BOU
0  3.4  2.4  2.80  2.60
1  3.5  2.0  2.75  2.75
2  4.0  2.0  3.00  3.00
3  3.5  2.0  3.50  2.50
4  3.0  2.0  2.00  2.00
```